# Swift TvOS: Overriding pressesBegan disables didSelectItemAt?

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos

I was previously able to use the method didSelectItemAt for a collectionView, but ever since implementing a function override for pressesBegan in its corresponding cells, didSelectItemAt no longer seems to be getting invoked.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // This used to work before overriding pressesBegan()...
}
```

The pressesBegan override in the corresponding cell:

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    super.pressesEnded(presses, with: event)
}
```

Are there adjustments I need to make so didSelectItemAt continues to work? Thanks.